# Change frequency of daemon in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon, ruby-on-rails-2

Every day, my Rails 2.3.16 web app checks data on many external websites to determine whether the links on these websites are still active or if they are 404. I receive many emails a day, and I'd like to change the frequency with which this process runs so that I don't get as many emails so frequently.

There is a file, domain_checker.rb, that lives in \web\current\lib\daemons. I can't see anything in the file that says when the daemon will run, however. It seems to run every morning at 06:55:00 +0000. Is there a way to change the frequency? Where should I start by looking? Sorry, I'm pretty amateurish at Rails and am fumbling my way through.

Here is the sanitized code from the domain_checker.rb file for reference. EDIT: I added code that I think suggests that ActiveMailer is sending these emails.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

#You might want to change this
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "production"

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment"
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
# require "system_timer"


class Net::HTTP
  alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    old_initialize(*args)
    @ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    @ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end
end

def get_url(uri_str,keywords, limit=10)
  raise ArgumentError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0

  url = URI.parse(uri_str)

  http.read_timeout = 10
  http.open_timeout = 10
  response = nil

  begin
  SANITIZED 
  end
  SANITIZED
  if keywords == nil or keywords == ""
    case response.code
    when /^2|3\d{2}/ then true
      #when Net::HTTPSuccess     then true
      #when Net::HTTPRedirection then true
      #when Net::HTTPFound       then true
      #when Net::HTTPRedirection then get_url(response['location'], limit - 1) 
    else
      response.error!
    end
  else
    if response.code =~ /^2|3\d{2}/ and response.body.include? keywords 
      true
      #when Net::HTTPSuccess     then true
      #when Net::HTTPRedirection then true
      #when Net::HTTPFound       then true
    elsif response.code == Net::HTTPRedirection then get_url(response['location'], limit - 1) 
    else
      @response_pass = nil
      response.error!
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  return false, "Timeout"
rescue TimeoutError
  return false, "Timeout"
rescue Exception
  if response != nil
    if not @response_pass =~ /^2|3\d{2}/  #check for errant 200/300s and get rid of them...
      return false, @response_pass, response['location'], response.body  #return response error code if it isn't 2xx-3xx
    else
      return false, nil
    end
  else
    return false, nil
  end
end


@lists = List.find(:all)
for list in @lists
  SANTIZED
if (@result == false) then
  # ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info("#{task.list.id}, #{task.list.name}, #{code}, #{url}.\n")  
  UserMailer.deliver_emaildown(task, "Business Website", code, url)
end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info("The site checker is still running at #{Time.now}.\n")

end

ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info("The site checker is done at #{Time.now}.\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't handle scheduling. Scheduling is typically delegated to a gem or something like `cron`.

Comment: Is it possible that ActiveMailer is related? I found this line of code in the domain_checker.rb that mentions UserMailer (added it to original question.) I think that connects to ActiveMailer. If so, is there a simple way to tell the daemon to check things once a week instead of immediately? If not, Vendor > Plugins > only includes integral_mailer, us_state_select_plugin, restful_authentication, thinking_sphinx, and will_paginate. I think these are all of my gems.

Comment: No, ActiveMailer is not related as it gets invoked by this code. The scheduler will be in charge of invoking this code. Look up cron jobs on your server.

Comment: Yup. I reviewed the cron jobs in the webmin system, and there was a cron job for the domain checker running daily. Edited frequency there. I'm guessing that'll do it. Thanks!